# IBM MobileFirst Platform Certificate pinning in Cordova Hybrid apps

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, hybrid-mobile-app

Im trying to implement certificate pinning in mobilefirst cordova-based hybrid application.
`mfp version is 7.1.0.00.20151227-1730.`

On api call `"WL.Client.pinTrustedCertificatePublicKey('mycert.cer')..."`,
I get this message inside cordova

`msgs = "56 F02 WLCertificatePinningPlugin626390484 sClass not found"`
Seems that cordova plugin is missing. I read all docs and there were no cordova sample. Only classic MFP project type.
How to properly confugure Certificate pinning for `mfp cordova` project type?

Comment: Did you change anything in the Cordova project prior to attempting certificate pinning?

Comment: Edited only www folder content. No new plugins added. I built Debug apk to read console messages from device. I will try new default cordova project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certificate Pinning is not supported in MFP-based Cordova applications in MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.1

Please see the feature parity list here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/c_cordova_vs_hybrid.html